# Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: this.boxes.push is not a function
> at WOW.WOW.doSync
> at WOW.<anonymous>
> at MutationObserver.observe.childList
> ```

can anyone tell me about this console error and solution?

Comment: This is most likely due to a plugin or theme. In the developer console, you should see which file triggers this error - can you post this information in your question? If it is not from WordPress core, you should contact the plugin/theme support.

Comment: This looks like something to do with wow.js, but there's nowhere near enough info to diagnose. Eitherway this isn't a WP problem, you need not restrict yourself to WP communities in finding a solution. You'd be better off asking on stack overflow, or better yet, your themes vendor or wow.js support